# How can I fix a Dygraphs Range Selection Bug?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I'm using the Dygraphs library to display a line chart of financial data.  When I enable the Range Selection option, there is a bug that causes dragging the selection handles to not be one-to-one, making it virtually unusable.

Here's an example of what it should look like if it's working: http://dygraphs.com/tests/range-selector.html
Here's an example of what happens when it's broken (this is how it works when I install it locally): http://dygraphs.com/gallery/#g/range-selector

I think that there is some javascript conflict that is causing this bug.  How can I go about fixing it or determining what's causing it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch. I've mentioned this to the author of the range selector. Looks like it has to do with position:relative. I'd suggest mentioning this on the dygraphs-users mailing list, or, reporting a bug at http://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues, and then you'll know when it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was introduced by the fix for issue #378. A new issue has been created: https://code.google.com/p/dygraphs/issues/detail?id=439

Comment: you should post only solution as answer. When you will have enough reputation you could post this in a comment

Comment: Thank you for posting a link to the issue; I'll watch that for a solution and post it here when it's fixed.